# Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close, on using fluttter_google_places

Tags: flutter, dart, google-api, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I have been getting this error every time i use the PlacesAutoComplete widget. Search/request/response everything is working perfectly, no crashes or anything. But the logs show me this error on every search.

I added two packages for it: flutter_google_places and google_web_services.

And i dont use streams at all. So this is a really strange error for me.

I followed a couple of online guides for this, can anyone explain what am i doing wrong?

Also, i see that this is a pretty basic way to implement places autocomplete. I would love your suggestions on a better way to implement google places search.

[image: Here is the error i get]

```
Future<void> _searchWithPlacesAutoComplete() async {
    Prediction _predictions = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
      context: context,
      apiKey: GOOGLE_API_KEY,
      onError: (response) => _showError(response),
      mode: Mode.overlay,
      language: "en",
      components: [Component(Component.country, "uk")],
      location: _currentLocation,
      radius: 50,
    );

    if (_predictions != null) {
      PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
          await GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: GOOGLE_API_KEY)
              .getDetailsByPlaceId(_predictions.placeId);
      final lat = detail.result.geometry.location.lat;
      final lng = detail.result.geometry.location.lng;

      setState(() {
        _markedPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
      });
      mapController.animateCamera(
        CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
          CameraPosition(
            target: _markedPosition,
            zoom: 16.0,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a plugin error which they have fixed in their git code. Unfortunately it hasn't been updated yet on their current release.

What you can do is integrate all of the src files in their github lib folder. It resolved the issue for me.

The exact steps:

[1] Go to https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_google_places/tree/master/lib/src
[2] Copied all the dart files into my project

Comment: Thank you, at least it clarifies that it wasnt my mistake

Answer (score 0):

```js
  StreamController<dynamic> subject = StreamController<dynamic>.broadcast();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.